# Workflow not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have found an unusual glitch in my workflow.
So I have list A and list B
So I have a workflow which allows to create a new item in another list.
So when I create an item in list A a new item gets created in list B and it works perfectly.
What I have found is when this new item is created in list B my Other workflow does not work in which I am performing a calculation on one  field.
Could you just help me out to find out how to make the other workflow work ?

Comment: The workflow that is not working is on list B?

Comment: did u tried and checked as if the lust B work flow trigger if u insert an item manually??

Comment: Yes it is list B. Yes manually it is working @md

Comment: both of ur WF r in 2013 platform??

Comment: Yes that is true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are facing, is a common problem. It is a limitation of SharePoint Workflow 2013. There are lots of assumption as why it is not working. But none of them are full proved.

So the workaround is to make the 2nd workflow in SharePoint Workflow 2010 platform. In this way, your process will work fine. Here is a [link](https://mobile.developer.com/net/sharepoint-2013-workflow-limitations-and-work-arounds.html) on this with more details if needed.

Comment: so you are saying the other workflows in list B should be of wf 2010 platform?

Comment: Yes. That will resolve the problem for now.

Comment: thank you. i will try this tomorrow and if it works i will mark this as an answer!

Comment: You are Welcome. Happy to help. :)